# How to discard changes of FileStream?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I have a simple question. I *may* be right but I want you people to ensure it since I am new at .NET.

```
StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(strFile);
SW.writeline("Hello");
SW.writeline("How are you?");
```

But in the middle, I don't want to save the data present in the `SW` variable, so what should I do? Should I use `delete` or `detach`?

Would reassigning memory to `SW` again cause any problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The StreamWriter class writes directly to the file.
Once you call `WriteLine`, it's too late to go back.

Answer (score 4):

`delete` and `detach` do not undo changes. `WriteLine` writes directly to the file. You might be interested in using `StringWriter` for this purpose though.

```
StringWriter SW = new StringWriter();
SW.writeline("Hello");
SW.writeline("how r u");

if (commit == true)
    File.WriteAllText (strFile, SW.ToString());
// else simply discard SW
```

Out of curiosity, why you would want to write something and then later discard it?